# I get differents geojson using GDAL ogr2ogr 1.10.1 or 1.9.0 version

Tags: geojson, gdal, ogr2ogr

I have two Ubuntu environments: one has installed GDAL 1.10.1 and second has installed GDAL 1.9.0.

If I run into env. GDAL 1.9.0: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON filename.geojson filename.kml` 
**filename.geojson** has this structure:

> {
>   "type": "FeatureCollection",
>   "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
>   "features": [
>   { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "TV01-CTRA. ALMERÍA", "description": "\n            \n
>   </div>
>   \n                    Ver detalle cámara</a>
>   \n            \n          ", "timestamp": null, "begin": null, "end": null, "altitudeMode": null, "tessellate": -1, "extrude": -1, "visibility": -1, "drawOrder": null, "icon": null }, 
>   "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4.35349321365356, 36.720241546630902 ] } },

but

> If I run same command into GDAL 1.10.1: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON filename.geojson filename.kml`
>   **filename.geojson** has this structure:
>   {
>   "type": "FeatureCollection",
>   "features": [
>   { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "TV01-CTRA. ALMERÍA", "Description": 
>   "</div> 
>   Ver detalle cámara</a>" },
>    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4.35349321365356, 36.720241546630902 ] } }
>   ,

There are a lots of differences for me (\n, tabs, blank space, crs line,...), and I need to generate second version, that is, I need generate second structure, but I have to run command into GDAL 1.10.1 version.

Which parameters I have to add?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Which GDAL version do you have to use - 1.9 or 1.10? You say the 1.10 output is correct and you also have to use 1.10, so I don't really see the issue here. The output from 1.9 doesn't look like valid GeoJSON. You can check the validity of the output with [geojson-lint](http://geojsonlint.com/)

Comment: oh! Sorry Kersten!!!

Comment: oh! Sorry Kersten!!! I wrote the question and I swapped file results. Thanks for your answer. I will rewrite question again.... Sorry and thanks a lot for your answer and your time :-)